# Is it probability density function too?

Tags: probability, density-function

Is it true that if $f(x)$ is probability density function then $f(-x)$ is probability density function too?

I don't even know how to start solving this problem. 
I tried to use a property of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) = 1$, but this way of proof didn't look right for me as I don't make any progress.
Thank You!

Comment: I assume you mean a density function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another proof : if a random variable $X$ has $f(x)$ as its pdf, then $-X$ has $f(-x)$ for its pdf, proving that $f(-x)$ is a pdf "per se".

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(x)$ is a probability density function.

Since $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the same is true of $f(-x)$.

To verify that $f(-x)$ is a probability density function, simply note that
\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(-x)\,dx\\[4pt]
=\;&\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} f(u)\,(-1)\,du&&\text{[using the substitution $x=-u$]}\\[4pt]
=\;&-\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} f(u)\,du\\[4pt]
=\;&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u)\,du\\[4pt]
=\;&\,1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}